# New Email hook in outlook

Tags: php, oauth, outlook

I have configured outlook email with oauth2 in my application and storing all emails in database but every time i have to fetch all the emails and then check in database and if find new then store in database.

Looking for a solution like if new email arrive in my inbox it ping my server and i store that email only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found API hook here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations. The Outlook Push Notifications REST API sends notifications via a webhook to a client-side web service to notify apps about changes to a user's mailbox data.